# Google earth browser plugin does not accept custom markers with custom images

Tags: markers, google-earth-plugin

I use custom images in google maps markers. I have included google earth control through google earth browser plugin. But they don't show custom images in google earth control? Any way I can solve this problem?

Thanks,
Jayesh

Comment: Where are you trying to load the images for your custom markers from? Are you defining them in javascript or KML?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you define your own symbols via Style/Iconstyle/Icon structure first, then you reference them in placemarks using the styleUrl element.

If you have a KML/KMZ that works well with the standalone GE application showing your custom icons, you can load it into the API using some JavaScript like

```
var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink('My cool KML/KMZ file');
var link = ge.createLink('Link to My cool ...');
link.setHref('http://www.here.on.the.net/MyCool.kmz');
networkLink.setLink(link);
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
```

If not you may get the stylemaps into the "internal KML" via some code. For example see [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/earth/documentation/placemarks.html#custom)

Hope this helps.
Good luck
MikeD

Answer (score 1):

Try absolute paths for the marker icon's images. Must be a bug of some sort.